# Loading the OneUI IDX V1.3 theme not working with mobile controls in Domino 9.0.1 FP2 IF1

Tags: mobile, dojo, xpages, lotus-domino

I have installed the latest version of Domino, 9.0.1 FP2 IF1 and have created a mobile application using the Mobile Controls and applied the theme OneUI IDX V1.3 but the theme do not get applied or is displayed wrong

```
IBM Domino (r) Server (64 Bit) (Release 9.0.1FP2 HF384 for Windows/64)
```

At first I could not get the page to load dojo 1.9.4 so I needed to add the line
xsp.client.script.dojo.version=1.9.4

Image below show that I am now using dojo 1.9.4, but the theme looks aweful

[image]

Image below show my XSP properties file

[image]

What can I do to get the OneUI IDX V1.3 theme working on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled mobile emulation in the browser? It looks from the screenshot like it is not enabled in the chrome developer tools. The mobile theme will only be applied when a mobile device is detected by the deviceBean

Comment: Thanks Brian, as you said, emulating a mobile device will indeed apply the theme correctly, however all the other themes do no require emulation, I do not want to create one webpage for desktop and one for mobile, I want one webpage to look the same across all devices.

Comment: What I mean is that I can disable the mobile theme and simply use xsp.theme=iphone on the xsp properties file and this will work across all devices, but it does not using the oneui_idx theme

Comment: 1. The IDX theme is a mobile-only theme, it's not designed to be used on desktop.
2. Selecting any theme in the mobile theme dropdown will mean that theme is only applied on a mobile device. Which I think you've covered in your second comment. 3. For using the same webpage across devices, I'd recommend the new responsive bootstrap themes in the extlib. The mobile theme dropdown + the mobile prefix etc is designed so that you can have one xpage for desktop, and another specifically for mobile

Comment: OK, good to know. but I do not see the point of a mobile-only theme. just imagine sending a link to a mobile webpage to a bounch of people. you have no idea in what device the user will open it in. if they open it in desktop it will look aweful. I hope you change this so that it can be used for all devices. I can use the device bean ofcorse but then I need to create two web pages

Comment: What you would usually do is have a piece of code in the page to redirect mobile users to the mobile version of the page (e.g. m_start.xsp), rather than let the desktop version load

Comment: For instance, in the discussion template, the main.xsp page has this: `<xp:this.afterPageLoad>
  <![CDATA[#{javascript:
            if(deviceBean.isMobile() || deviceBean.isTablet()){
                context.redirectToPage("/mobile.xsp", true);
            }else{
                context.redirectToPage("/allDocuments.xsp", true);  
            }
  }]]>
 </xp:this.afterPageLoad>`

Comment: In case you missed my edit above, it sounds like the responsive bootstrap themes are what you want, from Extlib 901 release 10. Develop once for all devices, with the webpage responsively adapting based on the device being used. The mobile theme approach is designed for creating 2 versions of your app/page, one for desktop & one for mobile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66919/discussion-between-thomas-adrian-and-brian-gleeson-ibm).